# Is xslt variable assignment done a single time?

Tags: xslt

I need to know if the variable **$transformed_date** will be evaluated each time, or is this variable as good as a variable affection (like in C, Java, etc.). I want to make sure I'm not reevaluating the same thing over and over.

```
<xsl:variable name="transformed_date" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime(concat(substring ($original_date, 1, 4),'-',substring ($original_date, 5, 2),'-',substring ($original_date, 7, 2),'T',substring ($original_date, 9, 2),':',substring ($original_date, 11, 2),':',substring ($original_date, 13, 2),'-00:00')), xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT5H'))"/>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring (xs:string($transformed_date), 6, 2) = '01'">
        <fo:inline>
            Jan.
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring (xs:string($transformed_date), 6, 2) = '02'">
        <fo:inline>
            Feb.
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:when>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in xslt can be set only once. Once set you cannot change them.

Comment: Ok, so the evaluation of the variable is "called" only once.

Comment: Yes. The evaluation should be called only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably assume the variable will only be evaluated once. But the processor might choose to do things differently; it's free to optimize. For example, hypothetically, if the variable is taking a lot of space and the processor is short of memory, it could release the space and re-evaluate the variable next time it's referenced. Or if the processor thinks that evaluation will be very cheap (e.g if you say select="23"), then the processor could decide to evaluate it every time it's referenced, if it thinks that is the best strategy.